# RegEx Search & Replace (via Dreamweaver CS5)

Tags: regex, search, replace, dreamweaver

I have to deal with a problem and maybe you can help.

I took over a Website with a lot of code and would like to have it run on PHP 5.4. 
But there are a LOT of statement's like this:

```
if($arrayname['keyname']>"") ....
```

I would like to replace them all with:

```
if(!empty($arrayname['keyname'])) ....
```

Doing it manually will take forever :-(

Do you know how to use Dreamweaver's CS5 search & replace with RegEx capabilites - unfortunately my RegEx knwoledge is limited.

Of course the regex must be "variable, as the arrayname and the keyname always changes.

Any help on finding the correct RegEx Stamtent is HIGHLY appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete and close this question:

In Dreamweaver search for  (Regex Search in Code):

```
if\(\$(\w+)\[['"](\w+)['"]\]>""\)
```

Replace by:

```
if(!empty($$1['$2']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex to find all occurrences of `if($arrayname['keyname']>"")`, whatever `arrayname` and `keyname` are, if only letters :

```
if\\(\\$[a-zA-Z]*\\[\'[a-zA-Z]*\'\\]>\"\"\\)
```

You'll have to find how to use [BackReferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in Dreamweaver. If it uses standard Regex, then use the tutorial in the link, it will be of great help for you.